# Xamarin.UITest 2.2.4 start session failed on the first test

Tags: visual-studio-mac, xamarin.uitest, xcode9.3

Since my macOS made me update to XCode 9.3 I had to upgrade Xamarin.UITest from 2.2.2 to 2.2.4.

The problem is that when I run all my tests, every single time the first one fails with the error attached. I think is not a test issue because all tests run correctly on a macOS with XCode 9.2 and Xamarin.UITest 2.2.2. Also if I delete that test, then the next one that is going to be the first one fails with the same error.

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you so much in advance!

```
1) SetUp Error : UI.Tests.TestDashboardDetailsPage(iOS)
Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : DeviceAgent start session failed: An error occurred while sending the request
  ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request
  ----> System.Net.WebException : Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Connection refused
  at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService+<RequestAsync>c__async14`1[T].MoveNext () [0x0010e] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService+<StartAppAsync>c__asyncE.MoveNext () [0x000ba] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchAppLocal (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, System.Boolean clearAppData) [0x00216] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, Xamarin.UITest.TestCloud.TestCloudiOSAppConfiguration testCloudAppConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient testCloudWsClient, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient xtcServicesClient, System.Boolean testCloudUseDeviceAgent) [0x0007a] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Execution.IExecutor executor) [0x002de] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x00000] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfigurator.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00017] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
  at UI.Tests.AppInitializer.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Platform platform) [0x00041] in <2cd1cd61003a486e92c6ffb9d58f1488>:0 
  at UI.Tests.TestDashboardDetailsPage.OneTimeSetUp () [0x00000] in <2cd1cd61003a486e92c6ffb9d58f1488>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
--HttpRequestException
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x004ab] in <7e581108ecb143d78ca072a020c287c3>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__47.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <7e581108ecb143d78ca072a020c287c3>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.HttpService+<PostAsJsonAsync>c__async3`1+<PostAsJsonAsync>c__AnonStorey11+<PostAsJsonAsync>c__async10[T].MoveNext () [0x00094] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.HttpService+<ExecuteRequestAsync>c__async5.MoveNext () [0x0008b] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.HttpService+<RequestAsync>c__async4`1[T].MoveNext () [0x0031b] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.HttpService+<PostAsJsonAsync>c__async3`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00132] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService+<RequestAsync>c__async14`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000be] in <1bd397951f434cd4913ddc08b7bc45af>:0 
--WebException
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in <a24e193d5cf14a42ac00ebaea26ec7bc>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <4fdc5ed61a074cafb49fa42deb20d521>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x002e7] in <7e581108ecb143d78ca072a020c287c3>:0 
--SocketException
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] in <a24e193d5cf14a42ac00ebaea26ec7bc>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0016d] in <a24e193d5cf14a42ac00ebaea26ec7bc>:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question. The issue is on XCode 9.3. Hope they fix this soon.

> Known Issues
>
> On macOS 10.13.4, booting iOS 11 and later in the Simulator may take several minutes the first time. (35628711)

SOURCE: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1

Answer (score 1):

I use a script that launches the simulator and waits before executing tests - this seems to help with these sorts of issues.

Also has an optional .app file path if you want to install the .app file before executing the tests as well:

```
#!/bin/sh -
# Boots the iOS simulator using specified OS and simulator name

set -e

SIMULATOR_VERSION="${1:?You must pass an iOS version as the first argument}"
SIMULATOR_NAME="${2:?You must pass a simulator name as the second argument}"
OPTIONAL_APP_PATH="$3"

SIMULATOR_GUID="$(xcrun simctl list | grep -vi unavailable | sed -e "1,/^-- iOS $SIMULATOR_VERSION --\$/d" -e '/^-- .* --$/,$ d' | grep -E "^\s+$SIMULATOR_NAME \(" | sed -e 's/^[^(]*(//g' -e 's/).*//g' | tail -1)"

if [ -z "$SIMULATOR_GUID" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Could not find simulator GUID for $SIMULATOR_NAME" >&2
    exit 123
fi

shutDownSimulator()
{
    GUID=$1
    echo "==> Shutting down simulator with GUID $GUID..."
    if xcrun simctl shutdown "$GUID" ; then
        sleep 10s
        echo "==> Successfully shutdown desired simulator."
    else
        echo "==> Desired simulator is already in shutdown state."
    fi
}

eraseSimulator()
{
    GUID=$1
    echo "==> Erasing..."
    xcrun simctl erase "$GUID"
    echo "==> Waiting for 30 seconds..."
    sleep 30s
}

bootSimulator()
{
    GUID=$1
    echo "==> Booting..."
    xcrun simctl boot "$GUID"
    echo "==> Waiting for 30 seconds..."
    sleep 30s
}

installOptionalAppFile()
{
    GUID=$1
    if [ -z "$OPTIONAL_APP_PATH" ] ; then
        echo "==> No app file to install specified, continuing..."
    else
        if [ -e "$OPTIONAL_APP_PATH" ]
        then
            echo "==> Installing app file at $OPTIONAL_APP_PATH"
            xcrun simctl install "$GUID" "$OPTIONAL_APP_PATH"
        else
            echo "==> App file was not found at path: $OPTIONAL_APP_PATH"
        fi
    fi
}

echo "==> Erasing and launching simulator with name: $SIMULATOR_NAME / iOS version: $SIMULATOR_VERSION / GUID: $SIMULATOR_GUID..."
shutDownSimulator "$SIMULATOR_GUID"
eraseSimulator "$SIMULATOR_GUID"
bootSimulator "$SIMULATOR_GUID"

echo "==> Launching Simulator app..."
open `xcode-select -p`/Applications/Simulator.app

echo "Waiting for simulator to boot for 120 seconds..."
sleep 120s

installOptionalAppFile "$SIMULATOR_GUID"

exit 0
```

2 minutes is probably excessive for wait time, but I do it just in case as some of my Mac Minis are a little old

Answer (score 0):

I too am having this issue with physical devices. I found that restarting the device is able to solve this problem. 
After restarting the device, the UITests are no longer failing on the first one.
We are able to restart the device using a library called libimobiledevice

https://www.mankier.com/1/idevicediagnostics

I'm running the UITests from Jenkins and in the build script before the tests are run we restart the device

```
idevicediagnostics -u[deviceUDID] restart
sleep 90s
```